# VBA crashes when trying to insert a multitude of CrossReferences

Tags: vba, ms-word

I encountered a mysterious problem when trying to run the following thing in VBA for Word:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim allHeadlines As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    allHeadlines = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)  ' Gets all headlines

    For i = 1 To UBound(allHeadlines)
        Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Nummeriertes Element", _
        ReferenceKind:=wdNumberRelativeContext, ReferenceItem:=Str(i), _
        InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, _
        SeparatorString:=" "
    Next
End Sub
```

The idea was simple: Just get all headlines and write them down automatically. (Actually, my intention was a bit different, but I broke the program down as much as I could.) "Nummeriertes Element" means "numbered element".

After 296 elements, the program crashes with a very unspecific error (Runtime Error '4198': "Command Failed") at the Selection.InsertCrossReference command. If I ignore the error and try to move on, Word crashes with an equally unspecific "heap damaged" error.

What also bothers me is that if I restart the Sub, it will fail immediately with Runtime Error '4198'. I have to restart Word completely to be able to run the Sub again, and then it will again crash at the same point (296 elements). Seems like some buffer is full and will not be cleared until I restart Word, but this is very annoying (I have *much* more than 300 headlines in this document).

I am quite at a loss here, because I do not really understand what is going on, or how to circumvent the problem. Does somebody else have an idea what is going on or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Of course, there might be something wrong with item #296. Cross references tend to get upset when adding or deleting paragraphs. Trying to read a corrupted reference may return the error you are experiencing. Try to identify the reference in question and determine if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: I checked this. If I remove item #296 or start with another item instead of the first one, it crashes at a different point. Seems to have nothing to do with the item itself.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is you don't have a `"Nummeriertes Element"` reference in your document perhaps **OR**, more likely, you have 295 `"Nummeriertes Element"` in your document. When it tries to insert the reference to `"Nummeriertes Element"(296)`, it bombs. The bombing after slamming through a couple pretty fast may just be an issue with Word (I've seen some pretty strange things happen with word and .docm corruptions). Unfortunately, you get that awful error which means absolutely nothing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim allHeadlines As Variant
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim i As Integer

    allHeadlines = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)  ' Gets all headlines

    For i = 1 To UBound(allHeadlines)
        Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeHeading, _
            ReferenceKind:=wdNumberRelativeContext, ReferenceItem:=i, _
            InsertAsHyperlink:=True, IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, _
            SeparatorString:=" "
    Next i
End Sub
```

This will cross reference to your *headings*. When you specify that your `ReferenceType` is `"Nummeriertes Element"` on the backend (I assume), it is doing a `GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeNumberedItem)` and then you specify you want to get it by the ordinal with `wdNumberRelativeContext` and trying to grab `GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeNumberedItem)(296)` which doesn't exist.

**But** when you change your `ReferenceType` to `wdRefTypeHeading` it will cross reference the heading itself at the ordinal and not your numbered list items. You can the drop then `str(i)` to just `i`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything. I copied your code and it produces the same error at the same position. I also ruled out that the item where it crashes might be the problem. Interesting idea, though.

Comment: I might try reinstalling Office if you haven't already. I've had to do it before for a frustrating thing or two. Unfortunate it didn't work for you as it did me. How big of a doc are we talking about?

Comment: Also, what version of office?

Comment: Word 2013, version 15.0.4027.1002. The most current version. The doc is relatively big, it is about 750 pages and roughly 700 headlines, but still not of a size where I would expect real trouble. I would not want to reinstall Office because that might be overkill for the problem at hand (and also, it might not fix the problem).